# Ember-cli, Masonry, Isotope, Packery. How to use?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, packery

I need to use them in my ember-cli project.

How to start?

I writed in terminal:

`bower install isotope --save`

then in my **ember-cli-build.js** I added `app.import ecc...`, but then I don't know what to do.

Where to put my intialization script, like this:

```
$('.grid').isotope({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
```

If I put it in **application.hbs** it give to me an error and when i change route with `{{#link-to}}` it doesn't work anymore.

What to do?

In the web there aren't many resources about this.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a component:

`ember g component isotope-grid`

Then, in component's `didInsertElement` hook you should call `isotope` on component's jQuery element:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['grid'], 

    didInsertElement() {
      this.$().isotope({
        // options
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
      });
    }
})
```

Then, instead of using `<div class="grid"></div>`, use:

```
{{#isotope-grid}}
  ... HTML goes here
{{/isotope-grid}}
```

Comment: Dear @Daniel, to close this question i want to know how to reproduce this (http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/aGvIq) in Ember, because, following your answer, I have this error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.$ is not a function` if I use this code: `didInsertElement() {
      this.$().packery({
        itemSelector: '.itemPack',
        gutter: 20
   });

   this.$().find('.itemPack').each( function( i, itemElem ) {
      var draggie = new Draggabilly( itemElem );
      // bind Draggabilly events to Packery
      this.$().packery( 'bindDraggabillyEvents', draggie );
    });`

Comment: What it means: `this.$()` in your code? Why I have to use it?