# How to use Packery with Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, packery

I just started ember and want to use [packery](https://packery.metafizzy.co) as layouting library. The ember app has been created via `ember new wep-app`. Packery has been installed via `npm install packery`. According to [ember dependency management](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/), I can load Packery via `app.import('node_modules/packery/js/packery.js')`

How do I use packery now? The `application.hbs` looks like this

```
<div class="grid">
   <div class="grid-item">cdsc</div>
   <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">...</div>
   <div class="grid-item">...</div>
</div>
```

But it seems not to work. In a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823929/ember-cli-masonry-isotope-packery-how-to-use), someone mentions the creation of a component `ember g component packery-grid`, which should be filled accordingly

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
   classNames: ['grid'], 
   didInsertElement() {
   this.$('.grid').packery({
       // options
       itemSelector: '.grid-item'
       });
   }
 });
```

Using a component, the `application.hbs` template should look like this:

```
{{#packery-grid}}
<div class="grid-item">cdsc</div>
<div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">...</div>
<div class="grid-item">...</div>
{{/packery-grid}}
```

However, this does not work either. What shall I do to have packery integrated into ember? I use ember 3.5.1.

**EDIT**: There is an ember component for packery as [well](https://www.emberobserver.com/addons/ember-cli-packery), which does not work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looking at packery's github, I think that `node_modules/packery/js/packery.js` is a wrong path. Correct one should be `node_modules/packery/dist/packery.pkgd.js`. You need to restart `ember serve` after this change in order to rebuild js
2. You might need to replace `this.$('.grid')` with `this.$()`

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like packery is a jQuery plugin, and not a module. Modules typically are what get imported.

For jQuery plugins, you need to load them in a script tag, maybe from vendor or public folders. (I don't know if you can use a script tag in HTML from node_modules)

But I highly recommend you check out css grid, and not use packery.
jQuery and jQuery plugins are unergonomic

Comment: are you refering to the css grid layout module?

Comment: This is not true. jQuery plugins can be imported in `ember-cli-build.js` using app.import

Comment: @mkultra it's a native feature of css, not a module. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ some info on usage and such

Comment: @gennady, all Js can be imported via app.import, however, it's unergonomic, and people in general should not be using jQuery with SPAs. Most of the apis are native now. And all of jquery's plugins have modern module based versions :)

Comment: I also didn't say jQuery plugins couldn't be imported, just that modules are what in typically imported.

Comment: Well, you said "For jQuery plugins, you need to load them in a script tag, maybe from vendor or public folders" and this is not true - just using `app.import` is enough, no additional script tags needed.
As for using jQuery or not - by default it is available in ember app and I don't see any valid reason (except trends and hype) to avoid it when it works just fine.

Comment: that's fair, but jQuery *is* on it's way out soon in Ember... it's not disabled by default, but is disableable. 
Also jQuery is just a huge library. 
to each their own I guess